# how can get the return of Update/Insert statement from nodejs driver

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I am using the Datasax nodejs driver for cassandra (https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver)
I am wondering if I can get the number of rows updated after executing an update statement.

Thanks,

Comment: Remember to accept/upvote answers provided. Or let us know for any questions/comments on the solution provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates to Cassandra is treated as another insert. In other words, there is no read before write (update in this case) in Cassandra. The updates are just writes to another immutable sstable and during read Cassandra stitches them together. Its during read, the latest value for that column is choosen.

So in short, there isn't a way in Cassandra to deduce the number of rows updated.

Comment: Any questions on the answer provided, otherwise pls remember to accept/upvote